# Firestore getAll() method doesnt accept FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference[] array

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use getAll() method in a firestore cloud function.
The problem is when I use an array in getAll(), it throws an error:

> [ts] Argument of type 'DocumentReference[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DocumentReference'.
>     Property 'id' is missing in type 'DocumentReference[]'.
>   const questionRefs: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference[]

`getAll()` method looks like, it accepts FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference[] array, but it doesn't.
Any idea, where the problem is?

```
const questionRefs = new Array<FirebaseFirestore.DocumentReference>();
for (const questionID of questions) {
    const ref = admin.firestore().collection('question-bank').doc(questionID)
    questionRefs.push(ref);
}
// then use getAll
admin.firestore().getAll(questionRefs).then(snapshots=>{
    snapshots.forEach(snapshot=>{
        // snapshot.data
        console.log('A');
    })
}).catch(err=>console.log('B'));
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to the API docs, the signature for [getAll()](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Firestore#getAll) looks like this:

> getAll(...documents) returns Promise containing Array of DocumentSnapshot

That `...documents` syntax in the argument is saying that you can pass a bunch of DocumentReference objects separately (as shown in the sample code in the doc).  But if you want to pass an array, you have to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert the array in to individual arguments:

```
admin.firestore().getAll(...questionRefs)
```