# How to fix "Property 'getAll' does not exist on type 'typeof firestore'"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4, angularfire

I'm getting a list of documents using an array of document IDs using *firestore.getAll()*. The problem is that I can't call getAll() since it doesn't seem to exist in firestore nor AngularFire, or I may be doing something wrong. 
Thank you in advance for your help and/or direction!

```
firebase.firestore.getAll(
[].concat(this.arrayOfUIDs).map(uid => this.firestore.doc(this.ref + uid))
```

Firebase is imported as:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

And .getAll() also does not exist in AngularFirestore

**Expected result**: Return an object containing a list of documents whose IDs exist in the arrayOfUIDs

**Result**: error in getAll() "Property 'getAll' does not exist on type 'typeof firestore'"

firestore doc: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/Firestore#getAll

Comment: Where have you got the idea that `getAll()` should exist? Are you following a tutorial? I can't see it existing in the firestore docs.

Comment: same here, but according to multiple sources who are facing my problem such as linked, this is how they solved it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49776395/firestore-getall-method-doesnt-accept-firebasefirestore-documentreference-ar

Comment: Oh, found it. But I still am unable to implement it https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/Firestore#getAll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getAll()` is a method provided by the node SDK.  Check carefully the link to the API docs that you provided.  `getAll()` is not currently available for web clients, though that might change in the future.  If you want to fetch multiple documents by IDs, you will have to [make a different query for each one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46721517/google-firestore-how-to-get-document-by-multiple-ids-in-one-round-trip).

Comment: Thank you. But how should that be done? Do I loop queries over the arrayOfIDs? But that would mean I'll call firestore _arrayOfIDs.length_ amount of times. Is there any way to do this more efficiently?

Comment: Read through the answers in the linked question.  There is really not a most efficient way.  Just get() each document.  It's not as bad as it sounds.

Comment: I'd have trouble bearing the fact that the client would have to download for example 1000 documents and throw away half of it. I'm currently making something similar to a social media timeline wherein posts from people who you follow appear in chronological order

Comment: Maybe ask a new question that gives more specific detail about what exactly you're trying to query, how your query actually performs, and what you've tried to do to optimize it that hasn't worked to your satisfaction.

Comment: Thanks Doug. I'll mark this as answered as this is about the getAll() method